# Rotating $y=x-2\sqrt{x}+1$ by $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I tried to rotate the equations
$$y=x-2\sqrt{x}+1 \quad\text{and}\quad y=x+2\sqrt{x}+1$$ (because of the two possible answers) $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise by using
$$y \cos(\theta)- x \sin(\theta)=(f(y \sin(\theta))+x \cos(\theta))$$ and ended up getting
$$2x^2=\sqrt{8y^2}-2(4 \sqrt{8y^2})+1$$
This is wrong because the vertex of the parabola should be on the $y$ axis at the $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{8}}$.

Where did I go wrong? Was it with
$$y \cos(\theta)-x \sin(\theta)=(f(y \sin(\theta))+x \cos(\theta))$$ or did I mess something else up along the way? How can I prevent from doing that mistake in the future?

Comment: It's hard to pin point where you did a mistake in your calculations if you don't show us your calculations. All I can tell is that something went wrong at "and ended up getting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the goal is to rotate the curve

$$\Gamma=\left\{(x,x-2\sqrt{x}+1):x\in[0,\infty)\right\}\cup\left\{(x,x+2\sqrt{x}+1):x\in[0,\infty)\right\}$$

by $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise, turning it into a parabola. Notice first that we can parameterize the curve by

$$F(t)=(t^2,t^2+2t+1)$$

for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (this is easy to arrive at by considering $t=\sqrt{x}$ and $t=-\sqrt{x}$ for the respective parts). This means that to rotate the graph, we can apply a rotation to this parameterization and obtain a parameterization of the rotated graph, which we will denote by $\Gamma'$. Now a general rotation about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by an angle $\theta$ (expressed in radians) can be represented as a matrix

$$R_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}.$$

In our case we want a rotation by $45^\circ$, which corresponds to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians, giving the appropriate rotation matrix as

$$R_{\pi/4}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\frac{\pi}{4} & -\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\sin\frac{\pi}{4} & \cos\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Applying this rotation we get

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
t^2\\
t^2+2t+1
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
-2t-1\\
2t^2+2t+1
\end{pmatrix},$$

and so we have the parameterization

$$G(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-2t-1,2t^2+2t+1)$$

for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ of $\Gamma'$. All that remains is to rewrite this as a function graph. In particular, notice that as $t$ goes through all of $\mathbb{R}$ we can transform $t$ in a suitable way until we can read off the graph. We notice that

$$H(t):=G\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\left(t,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(2t^2+1)\right)$$

still parameterizes $\Gamma'$, and so it follows that the rotated graph is the parabola given by the equation

$$y=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(2x^2+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

From the two equations, we can write

$ \pm 2 \sqrt{x} = (y - x - 1) $

Squaring,

$ 4 x = y^2 + x^2 + 1 - 2 x y - 2 y + 2 x $

Which simplifies to

$ x^2 + y^2 - 2 x y - 2 y - 2 x + 1 = 0 $

Which is a parabola.

The image of a point $(x, y)$ after rotation by an angle $\theta$ counter clockwise is the point $(u, v)$ given by

$ u = x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta $

$ v = x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta $

From which it follows that

$ x = u \cos \theta + v \sin \theta $

$ y = - u \sin \theta + v \cos \theta $

Substituting $\cos \theta = \sin \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $ results in

$ x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( u + v) $

$ y = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (- u + v) $

Substitute these into the quadratic equation of the function which we obtained above, you get the equation of the rotated parabola,

$ \dfrac{1}{2} \left( (u + v)^2 + (- u + v)^2 - 2 (u + v)(-u+v) \right) - \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}} ( u + v - u + v) + 1 = 0 $

This simplifies to

$ 2 u^2  - 2 \sqrt{2} v + 1 = 0 $

Replace $(u,v)$ with $(x,y) $, you get the parabola

$ 2 x^2 - 2 \sqrt{2} y + 1 = 0 $

i.e.

$ y = \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} x^2 $

Which has the expected $y$-intercept.

Comment: Thankyou! i think i just got confused on the (u,v) part when I first tried this.